# 親子関係でないviewcontrollerに戻るを適用したい。

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

こんにちは。いつもお世話になっています。

いま自分の作ってるプログラムでTodoリストてきなものがあるのですが。

依存関係が
1：mypage->やること作成->やること詳細というviewcontrollerの依存関係があるのですが、
その際もう一つ依存関係が有りまして、2：mypage->やること一覧->やること詳細という流れの依存関係があります。

そこで自分は1の流れを通って2のフローで戻るようなプログラムを書きたいのです。

言語はswift2.0を使っています。
ぜひお力をお貸しください。

Answer (score 2):

`UINavigationController`を使っている前提でお話しますと、[`setViewControllers(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers:animated:)で実現できます。

`UINavigationController`は`ViewController`をスタック構造で管理しているだけのクラスです。通常は`push/pop`で操作するかと思いますが、`setViewControllers()`を使うことで`UIViewController`のスタックの内容を直接操作できます。

実装的には、「やること作成->やること詳細」での画面遷移メソッドを`push`から`set`に変えます。このとき、`setViewControllers()`に`[mypage, やること作成, やること詳細]`の`ViewController`の`Array`を渡します。

Comment: こんばんわ。回答有難うございます。
とても勉強になります！
すみません。情報が足りませんでしたね。。。実はUINavigationControllerではなくセグエを使っています。そちらの方で何か良い手はご存知ありませんか？

Comment: `Unwind segue`をキーワードにして、ネット検索すると、お知りになりたい情報に、多数ヒットしますよ。

Comment: Unwind segueを使って調べたのですがわからないのです。。。すみません。。。（泣）
１のフローでやること詳細までいって２のやること一覧に行けないのでしょうか？

Comment: @take セグエというのはシーン間の繋がり（画面遷移）をオブジェクトで表現したものです。親子関係や依存関係が実際にどういうものなのかはセグエを使っているかどうかからは分かりません。その辺りや、storyboardのみで実装したいのか、コードで実装したいのか、現状ではどこまで実現できているかなどを質問に追記してみてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。
HTTPなども使っているので一応コード実行もしています。
この場を借りて質問なんですがセグエはあれは前のview contollerで次のviewcontollerのインスタンスを作ってると思っていたのですがその理解で合っていますか？

Comment: @take それはコメントの短い文章だと正しく理解して頂けるか難しい質問ですね。StoryBoardを利用しているという前提になりますが、VCやセグエのインスタンスが実際に作成されるのはコンパイル時で、実行時にはそれぞれに割り振られた識別子を利用してデコードしています。ただし`initWithcoder()`は圧縮されたそれらインスタンスを復元するためのイニシャライザですが、このタイミングで「インスタンスを作っている」と表現することもできます。

Comment: @take つまるところ、StoryBoardとはViewController（シーン）とセグエ（シーン間の繋がり）をGUIで事前に作成し、圧縮してパッケージングする仕組みなのです。セグエが次のVCを作っているわけでも、VCがセグエを作っているわけでもありません。それらはStoryBoard上では、一連のシーン（ストーリー）を表現するオブジェクトとして並列に扱われます。

Comment: なるほど。initWithcoder()はシングルトンみたいなやつのっていう理解で大丈夫ですか？(すいませんざっくりで。)
ならば上の質問においての解決法または代替の方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

そもそも論なのですが、その画面遷移にちょっと違和感を感じました。

Comment: そうなんですよ。。。こんな質問してる私が言うのもあれですがweb版作ってる友だちがいてこれに合わせることが今回の仕様なので。しかたがないねってことなのです。普通アプリは相対的に遷移しないと思うのですよ。。。(これであっていますかね。。。？この回答についての返答は。)

Comment: 経緯を理解しました！なるほどです。。。

Comment: ご理解いただけてさいわいです笑
 JohnyDgoodeさんはなにかいい手はありませんか？

Comment: popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NOでmypageに戻って即座にpushviewcontroller animated:NOでやること一覧にいくのはどうですか？？遷移中は画面暗くしてインジケーターでも出しておいて。強引に見えますが、NavigationControllerの遷移に沿ってるのでデグレ率は低めかと。

Answer (score 1):

Web版に仕様を合わせようとしているのでしたら
どうして`UINavigationController`を使わないのですか?

Webの画面遷移と`UINavigationController`は
とても親和性が高いと思うのですが。

むしろWeb版で「1の流れを通って2のフローで戻る」というのを
どう実現しているのか不思議です(というか、具体的にどういう
遷移なのか今一つ理解できていません)。

そこをWeb版でどうやっているのかきちんと分析した上で
`UINavigationController`ベースで同じようにすれば
よいのではないかという気がします。

その際、あなたが今使っている「戻る」というキーワードが
具体的にどうすることなのか明確にしておくべきだと思います。
Webなら「戻る」と言っても、
ブラウザの「戻る」ボタンで前の画面に戻るケースと
画面内の「戻る」ボタンで元の画面と同じURLに遷移する
(実際には戻っているのではなく新しい画面を生成している)
ケースの2種類ありますよね。

ちなみに「UINavigationControllerではなくセグエを使っています」
と書かれていますが`UINavigationController`を使うか否かと
セグエを使うか否かは全く別の話です。
`UINavigationController`で画面を構成してpushセグエで遷移する
こともできます。
そこは理解していて、
・`UINavigationController`を使っていない
ということと
・セグエを使っている
ということの
2つを上記1文で表しただけという認識でよいのでしょうか?